# How can I use javascript std input/output in repl.it

Tags: javascript, node.js, replit

I wrote a [simple program](https://repl.it/@AshiqurRahman1/Stdin-and-Stdout-in-jS) for finding the factorial of a given number, which I want to run on `repl.it`. I would like to take standard input and output from the command line during it's execution.  How can this be achieved?

Comment: can you post some code please

Comment: https://repl.it/@AshiqurRahman1/Stdin-and-Stdout-in-jS

Answer (score 1):

To use stdin/stdout in NodeJS on Repl.it, you have to add a file first, this will switch repl.it from repl mode to project mode.

See: https://repl.it/@amasad/Stdin-and-Stdout-in-jS